# Update current value on tkinter interface

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter interface with a combobox and some entry
which look like this :

```
portentry = tk.Entry(root)
portentry.place(x=10, y=110, width=50)
portentry.lift(aboveThis=l)
portentry.insert(0,defaultswitch("port"))
```

defaultswitch is a function which load a default value, or a saved value, because in fact, the combobox in my interface is used to select a version of something, and all entry are parameters.
I have a save button which saves the value of the entry in a JSON, as an object of the version, so I have different entry value for all version. So after the startup, the combobox is on the last used version, and value entries are loaded from the JSON, and load assigned value.

What I want is that when select other versions in the combobox, entry are reloaded too. because actually, they rest on the last version used when I change the version.

Comment: you can use `bind()` with event `<<ComboboxSelected>>` to assign function to `Combobox` which will update other values. This was described few times in questions on Stacokverflow - probably even there was one question few days ago. If you use Google to search `Combobox bind selected` then probably you find many solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW: There was many questions on Stackoverflow which shows this.

---

You can us `bind()` with event `<<ComboboxSelected>>` to assign function to `Combobox` which may update value `Entry` when you select new value in `Combobox`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# --- functions ---

def on_select(event):
    #print('[DEBUG] event:', event)
    #print('[DEBUG] event.widget:', event.widget)
    #print('[DEBUG] event.widget.get():', event.widget.get())
    #print('---')

    #selected = combo.get()
    selected = event.widget.get()

    entry.delete('0', 'end')
    entry.insert('end', selected)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=['A', 'B', 'C'])
combo.pack()

combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_select)

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
#entry.insert(0, '?')
entry.insert('end', '?')

root.mainloop()
```

Using `event.widget.get()` instead of `combo.get()` this function can assign to different widgets and it will get value from correct widget.

---

**EDIT:**

Example which uses `Combobox` to change values in different widgets - `Label`, `Button`, `Entry`, `Listbox`, `Text` and even in other `Combobox`

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# --- functions ---

def on_select(event):
    print('[DEBUG] event:', event)
    print('[DEBUG] event.widget:', event.widget)
    print('[DEBUG] event.widget.get():', event.widget.get())
    print('---')

    selected = event.widget.get()

    label['text'] = selected

    button['text'] = selected

    entry.delete('0', 'end')
    entry.insert('end', selected)

    combobox2_values = {
        'A': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
        'B': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
        'C': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
    }

    #combobox2.delete('0', 'end')
    combobox2['values'] = combobox2_values[selected]

    listbox.delete(0, 'end')
    for item in combobox2_values[selected]:
        listbox.insert('end', item)

    values = combobox2_values[selected]
    values_str = ', '.join(values)

    #text.delete('1.0', 'end')
    text.insert('end', selected + ': ' + values_str + '\n')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, values=['A', 'B', 'C'])
combobox.pack()

combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_select)

# --- other widgets ---

label = tk.Label(root, text='?')
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='?')
button.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
#entry.insert(0, '?')
#entry.insert('end', '?')

combobox2 = ttk.Combobox(root)
combobox2.pack()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

text = tk.Text(root, width=30, height=10)
text.pack()
#text.insert('1.0', '?\n')
#text.insert('end', '?\n')

# --- 

root.mainloop()
```

[image]  [image]

Comment: I added `Listbox` to example. And I show it on screenshots.